# Install of 20.18 from usb fails /casper/vmlinuz has invalid signature - with secure boot disabled get blank screen

Tags: grub2, system-installation, usb, uefi, secure-boot

Installing 20.18 from usb with 'quiet splash' removed I get
'Booting from command list
/casper/vmlinuz has invalid key'

With Secure Boot disabled, grub gets as far as 'Booting a command list' and then stops with no further message.

Asus S400C laptop; Aptio Setup Utility

There is no usable o/s on the computer. It did have Ubuntu 18, but the disk is irretrievably corrupted. Windows was deleted. On the old o/s I can get as far as the very basic shell and the commands available in it, but they cannot see the root filesystem; only /dev and /run are listed, although the top-level directories of / are there.

What is causing grub to stop?
Alternatively, how can I sign the kernel?

Comment: There was probably an error in downloading or flashing the installation media. Verify the checksum of the downloaded ISO and re-flash the image.  I recommend balenaEtcher for flashing because it is cross platform and user friendly.

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format (for server & desktop installs), eg. 20.10 means the 2020-October release. There is no 18th month so it's possible you have a forgery.  Did you verify your image (assuming it's a legit Ubuntu) - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0   Ubuntu does also have *yy* format releases, but they are different products, eg. Ubuntu Core 18 or the 2018 release intended for appliances/devices & cloud use (*yy* releases are *snap* only, less powerful thus smaller in size which is itself a plus)

Comment: No. It's my error. I can't read what's on the usb stick until I can boot it, so I was going from memory. It's a genuine download from Ubuntu.